# Fatal erro :CMakeFiles/hnswlib.dir/hnswalg.cpp.d: :no such file or director during compiling c++ with make

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

This is fine when I compile with cmake

```
#cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/zmd/ivf-hnsw-master/hnswlib
```

, then use the make command and get an error which I have known is due to a missing.d dependency file

```
#make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hnswlib.dir/hnswalg.cpp.o
cc1plus: fatal error: CMakeFiles/hnswlib.dir/hnswalg.cpp.d: no such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

how can i get this dependency file ?
here is  cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

# hnswlib project
project(hnswlib C CXX)

# specify output bin_path and lib_path
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

file(GLOB headers ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)
file(GLOB sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)

# Build each source file independently
include_directories(../../) # ivf-hnsw root directory

add_library(hnswlib STATIC ${headers} ${sources})
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Ofast -lrt -DNDEBUG -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CXX0X -openmp -march=native -fpic -w -fopenmp -ftree-vectorize -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=0" )
target_link_libraries(hnswlib)
```

i have known is due to a missing.d dependency file and how can i get this dependency file ?

Comment: My (possibly wrong) understanding is that you shouldn't need to do anything to get such files generated. See the `CMAKE_DEPFILE_FLAGS_` variable definitions in the `Modules/` folder of your CMake installation. I'm not sure why things are going wrong for you.

Comment: My running terminal is ubuntu18.04.4.Using the command,
`whereis cmake`.then get
`cmake: /usr/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/share/cmake /usr/local/OpenBLAS/lib/cmake /usr/share/man/man1/cmake.1.gz'
 which is my cmake installation path,

Comment: well, it does look lik eyou're using some pretty old (nowadays) tool versions. GCC is at v11/12 now, and CMake is at v3.25. What CMake version do you actually have installed? Any chance you can do an upgrade to more recent tool versions?

Comment: Year, I have upgraded my cmake version, then a new error `/ hnswlib/hnswalg. H: ": fatal error: faiss/Heap. H: No to the file or directory` it shows that I couldn't find the include file, but I added the line `include_directories(.. /.. /) `in CMakelist.txt. The faiss folder is also located in this path, and the Heap.h file can also be found in the faiss folder. How do I solve this problem

Comment: ask a new question (new question post) and provide a [mre] in that new question.

Comment: I see what's going on here, it's the relative paths, I'm always executing cmak in a new folder, so I'm having problems with the paths, maybe I can change it to absolute paths, right,But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the.d file could not be found because I could not search the header file needed to generate the object file when compiling the link. After I tried again in the updated cmake version, the file name that was not searched appeared. After adding the absolute path of the corresponding file to CMakelist.txt, the compilation was successful

Comment: If you solved the problem, share the exact solution, i.e. your modified `CMakeLists.txt` for others with the similar issue.